# Why can't I have duplicate definitions in files that are not imported?

Tags: visual-studio-2010

Say I have five files; fileA.cpp, fileA.hpp, fileB.cpp, fileB.hpp, and main.cpp. Both header files define the function `void help()`. I want to switch between using the function in fileA.cpp and fileB.cpp in my main.cpp file. I have tried just switching the header include, but visual studio complains about duplicate definitions.

Answer (score 1):

That is a linker error. There will be a `fileB.obj` and `fileA.obj` (and `main.obj`) being linked together to form the executable. `fileA.obj` and `fileB.obj` will both contain definitions for `void help()`, causing the multiple definitions error. It is unrelated to changing the include directive in `main.cpp`.

Suggest enclosing `void help()` in a `namespace`:

**fileA.hpp**:

```
namespace filea
{
    void help();
}
```

**fileA.cpp**:

```
namespace filea
{
    void help()
    {
        // implementation
    }
}
```

**fileB.hpp**:

```
namespace fileb
{
    void help();
}
```

**fileB.cpp**:

```
namespace fileb
{
    void help()
    {
        // implementation
    }
}
```

**main.cpp**:

```
#include <fileA.hpp>
using filea::help;

//#include <fileB.hpp>
//using fileb::help;
```